# Integral and calculation

Tags: integration

I'm solving some exercises about integrals but I can't solve this one, can someone explain the step-to-step please?

Let $\phi:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with a second derivative, where $f(0)=0$ and $f(\pi)=3$, calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi}[f(t)+f''(t)]sin(t)dt$

Comment: Is $f = \phi$?  ${  }$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing partial integration twice,
$$\int_0^\pi f(t) \sin t dt=-f(t)\cos t + \int_0^\pi f'(t) \cos t dt\\
=-f(t)\cos t + f'(t)\sin t - \int_0^\pi f''(t) \sin t dt
$$
$$\therefore \int_0^\pi f(t) \sin t dt+\int_0^\pi f''(t) \sin t dt=\left[-f(t)\cos t + f'(t)\sin t\right]_0^\pi\\
=-f(\pi)\cos \pi + f'(\pi)\sin \pi=f(\pi)=3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets focus on the second integral:
$$
\int_0^\pi f''(t)\sin t\ \mathrm dt
$$
and integrate by parts:
$$
\int_0^\pi f''(t)\sin t\ \mathrm dt=\left[f'(t)\sin(t)\right]_0^\pi-\int_0^\pi f'(t)\cos(t)\mathrm dt=-\int_0^\pi f'(t)\cos(t)\ \mathrm dt
$$

Integrate by parts again
$$
\int_0^\pi f''(t)\sin t\ \mathrm dt=\left[-\cos(t)f(t)\right]_0^\pi-\int_0^\pi f(t)\sin(t)\ \mathrm dt
$$

From this point, I believe you can finish the problem yourself.